# If hasClass not working on document.ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to change background color, when slide element has class (slick-current) but it's not working at all on document.ready, even can't display something in console.log(). Console not displaying any errors. (.content is a parent element of .slider-container).

Here is html code:

```
<div class="slider-container">
    <div class="single-item">
        <div class="slick-slide " id="slide-1" data-slick-index="0" ><h3>1</h3></div>
        <div class="slick-slide slide-2" data-slick-index="1" ><h3>2</h3></div>
        <div class="slick-slide slide-3" data-slick-index="2" ><h3>3</h3></div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Here is jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    if($("#slide-1").hasClass(".slick-current")){
        $('.content').css("background-color", "yellow")
        console.log('ggh');
    }
});
```

Comment: remove the `.` when using `hasClass()` ► `hasClass("slick-current")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using [**hasClass**](https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/) you should leave out the `.`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  if ($("#slide-1").hasClass("slick-current")) {
    $('.content').css("background-color", "yellow")
    console.log('has class slick-current');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slider-container">
  <div class="single-item">
    <div class="slick-slide slick-current" id="slide-1" data-slick-index="0">
      <h3>1</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="slick-slide slide-2" data-slick-index="1">
      <h3>2</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="slick-slide slide-3" data-slick-index="2">
      <h3>3</h3>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove "." in the hasClass brackets and it should works :)
Here's documentation to hasClass https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/
Check here how to use it properly.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `.` in the `hasClass`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  if ($("#slide-1").hasClass("slick-current")) {
    $('.content').css("background-color", "yellow")
    console.log('ggh');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slider-container">
  <div class="single-item">
    <div class="slick-current" id="slide-1" data-slick-index="0">
      <h3>1</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="slick-slide slide-2" data-slick-index="1">
      <h3>2</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="slick-slide slide-3" data-slick-index="2">
      <h3>3</h3>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```